# update line below or next line if the current line condition is met with awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file which I want to update in place.
IT contains the following text:

```
distributed_tracing:
   enabled: false
cross_application_tracer:
   enabled: true
```

I want to update distributed tracing to true. How can I update the next line if the current line contains "distributed_tracing"

Any solution using awk or sed will be helpful.

I tried the following solution but it did not work:

```
cat /file.yml | sed -e "s/(distributed_tracing:.*\n.*)enabled: false/enabled: true/g" > /file1.yml.new
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/distributed_tracing/{n=NR} n&&NR==n+1{sub("false","true")}1' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

note, added `n&&` not to match first line.

Comment: this edit the files and prints it but does not save it in place

Comment: I like the idea of setting a variable to NR instead of just a flag, but `NR==n+1` will be true on the first line of input unless you initialize n to something non-zero.

Comment: echo "$(awk '/distributed_tracing/{n=NR} NR==n+1{sub("false","true")}1' /file)" > file

Comment: @Ankit, the temp file method is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Go old school:

```
 printf '/distributed_tracing/+1s/false/true/\nw\n' | ed -s input-file
```

Comment: `ed` is sadly underappreciated these days.

Answer (score 0):

This worked,

```
echo "$(awk '/distributed_tracing/{n=NR} NR==n+1{sub("false","true")}1' /file)" > file
```

Thanks @karafka

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/distributed_tracing:/{n;s/false/true/}' file
```

If a line contains `distributed_tracing:`, print it and then fetch the next line. If that line contains `false` replace it by `true`.